# WMIC return No Instance(s) Available when run directly .cmd file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmi, wmic

I am trying to query WMIC in the for loop. When I run the query command in cmd.exe

```
WMIC PATH Win32_DiskPartition WHERE (DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #1") GET Type /value
```

result is good. But I run query.cmd, it show No Instance(s) Available.

https://abload.de/img/ooo6vkr6.png

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "InputFile=C:\Users\NIMDA\AppData\Local\Temp\aa.txt"
IF EXIST "%InputFile%" (DEL /f /q "%InputFile%")
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('"WMIC PATH Win32_DiskPartition WHERE (DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #1") GET Type /value"') DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%H IN ("%%G") DO (
        CALL ECHO %%H>> "%InputFile%"
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
pause
```

How to fix this ?.

Comment: Here is a page that will show how to do it in PowerShell, Microsoft's stated way forward. https://sqladm.blogspot.com/2010/12/disk-info.html

Comment: You need to escape the comma in `Disk #0^, Partition #1` as this part appears unquoted in your `for /F` command line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of examples which do it in different ways!

Using `Find`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "InputFile=%TEMP%\aa.txt"
For /F Tokens^=4* %%A In ('
    "WMIC Partition Where "DeviceID Like 'Disk #0%%'" Get DeviceID,Type 2>NUL|Find "Partition #1""
')Do @For /F Tokens^=* %%A In ("%%B")Do >>"%InputFile%" Echo Type=%%A
```

Using `Like`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "InputFile=%TEMP%\aa.txt"
For /F Tokens^=* %%A In ('
    "WMIC Partition Where "DeviceID Like 'Disk #0%%' And DeviceID Like '%%Partition #1'" Get Type /Value 2>NUL"
')Do @For /F Tokens^=* %%B In ("%%A")Do >>"%InputFile%" Echo %%B
```